# Sum Values from 2nd Google sheets with the date specified in 1st Sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have two separate Google-sheets. I am trying to import the sum of data from my first sheet between a date range that I have in my 2nd google sheet.
Example: My first GoogleSheet contains this data:

[image: sheet1]

My 2nd sheet contains the date range in which I want to carry out my calculation.
In the image below I am adding the sum(price) from my first GoogleSheet when date range between Date range1 and Date Range2 in my 2nd GoogleSheet.
[image: My second sheet]

If this was on the same Googlesheet under different tab, we could have used sumifs. Since this is in two different GoogleSheets importrange with sumif is throwing an error.

Hope someone can help me with the formula to carry out this calculation.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

For your case is a very straightforward case of [`SUMIFS`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3238496?hl=en) main goal.

You have a range that you would like to sum `B1:B10` based on multiple conditions (in your case after one date and before the other).

#### Solution

```
=SUMIFS(Sheet1!B1:B10, Sheet1!A1:A10, ">=" & A2, Sheet1!A1:A10,"<=" & B2 )
```

Please adapt this to match your ranges, look at the example below to understand what range is the summing range and which are the conditions one.

#### Example

In this case is all on the same sheet so you can see how everything is coming together, but for multiple sheets is just the same.
[image: Final Result]